# Facebook SDK Swift4 unrecognizable selector Profile

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, facebook

im working with Facebook sdk in swift3 to know when Profile change

in my view load

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        basededatos=BaseDeDatosFirebase()
        mensajes = MensajesView(vistaRoot: self)
        print("Notificacion")

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:"onProfileUpdated:", name:NSNotification.Name.FBSDKProfileDidChange, object: nil)
    }
 func onProfileUpdated(notification: NSNotification)
    {print("cambiando")

    }
```

But when I login in facebook:

> [ProcIOS.MainViewController onProfileUpdated:]: unrecognized selector
>   sent to instance 0x7fe4b6d0ef70'
>   *** First throw call stack:

Comment: You are using the incorrect Selector syntax.

Comment: and with is the correct syntax?

Comment: Read the linked duplicate.  Use `#selector`.